# How can I select own text inside element except included tags with phpQuery?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, phpquery

```js
function getPrice() {
  return $('.product__element').contents().eq(0).text();
}

console.log(getPrice()); //returns **A**.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product__element">
  A
  <span>B</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sb67Lwpx/

But **phpQuery**

```
pq('.product__element')->contents()->eq(0)->text();
```

returns **A B**.

How to get only **A** in phpQuery ?
HTML can not be edited.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for phpQuery.

`pq('.product__element')->clone()-children()->remove()->end()->text();`

returns A.